# Calculate the time in Java (Android Studio)

Tags: java, android, countdowntimer, valueconverter

I got one time from the server. This time saved in a array and I show this time in TextView with this code in adapter:

```
txttime.setText(time[position]);
```

I have current time with `System.currentTimeMillis()` and I want to calculate Different between `System.currentTimeMillis()` and my time that got from server.
I want to use this result in `CountDownTimer()`

```
new CountDownTimer(result, 1000)
```

Thanks for your advice :)

Comment: How does the time from your server look like?

Answer (score 1):

Try this. Think that time1 is your current time and time2 is server time which you are getting.

```
String Time1 = "10/02/14 09:29:50";
        String Time2 = "11/04/14 09:12:43";

            // date format
            SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");  

        Date d1 = null;
        Date d2 = null;
        try {
            d1 = format.parse(Time1);
            d2 = format.parse(Time2);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }    


        long diff = d2.getTime() - d1.getTime();
        long diffSeconds = diff / 1000;         
        long diffMinutes = diff / (60 * 1000);         
        long diffHours = diff / (60 * 60 * 1000);                      
        System.out.println("Time in seconds: " + diffSeconds + " seconds.");         
        System.out.println("Time in minutes: " + diffMinutes + " minutes.");         
        System.out.println("Time in hours: " + diffHours + " hours.");
```

Comment: Style of my time in server is => "1502917200"
How can I change this style to your style => "10/02/14 09:29:50"

Comment: you have to ask your backend developer to give in correct format